# Plotting ROC curve for outlier detection algorithms

Tags: rapidminer

What are the steps to plot ROC curve for LOF or any other outlier detection algorithm in RapidMiner? I have generated the data using 'Generate data'operator and want to get the ROC curve for the LOF algorithm. But i get an error-"the process should only have 2 labels(normal and outlier). I cannot understand what to do.
Here is the XML code:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="6.2.000">
<context>
<input/>
<output/>
<macros/>
</context>
<operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="6.2.000" expanded="true" name="Process">
<process expanded="true">
<operator activated="true" class="generate_data" compatibility="6.2.000" expanded="true" height="60" name="Generate Data" width="90" x="45" y="75">
<parameter key="target_function" value="gaussian mixture clusters"/>
<parameter key="number_examples" value="200"/>
<parameter key="number_of_attributes" value="2"/>
</operator>
<operator activated="true" breakpoints="after" class="anomalydetection:Local Outlier Factor (LOF)" compatibility="2.3.000" expanded="true" height="94" name="Local Outlier Factor (LOF)" width="90" x="179" y="120">
<parameter key="nominal_measure" value="JaccardSimilarity"/>
<parameter key="parallelize evaluation process" value="true"/>
</operator>
<operator activated="true" breakpoints="after" class="anomalydetection:Generate ROC" compatibility="2.3.000" expanded="true" height="130" name="Generate ROC (2)" width="90" x="380" y="120">
<parameter key="label value for outliers" value="outlier"/>
</operator>
<connect from_op="Generate Data" from_port="output" to_op="Local Outlier Factor (LOF)" to_port="example set"/>
<connect from_op="Local Outlier Factor (LOF)" from_port="example set" to_op="Generate ROC (2)" to_port="example set"/>
<connect from_op="Generate ROC (2)" from_port="roc set" to_port="result 1"/>
<portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
<portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
<portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
</process>
</operator>
</process>
```

Comment: When you compute the performance metrics, you can select AUC for example and plot the ROC. For example see the `03_Validation/14_LiftChart` sample process.

Comment: @GáborBakos... I have taken the iris dataset as the input. Then i have applied the LOF operator to this. Now on applying . the 'Generate ROC'operator, it asks me to fill a label value. This is where i am stuck. Please help.

Comment: Could you share your workflow? Which version of RapidMiner do you use?

Comment: I am currently using RapidMiner version 6.2.000

Comment: @GáborBakos....How do i share the main process window with you?? I'n new to stackoverflow...so i'd be grateful if you could help me out with this.

Comment: You should edit your post. To achieve the xml, you need to add the XML view (View|Show View|XML) and copy the content of that window to the question. (Or just save the process and open with an editor and copy that content.)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately I do not have `Generate ROC` and `Local Outlier Factor (LOF)` nodes, I guess those require extensions. For your actual problem: The iris dataset contains label with 3 values, your example contains 4, for ROC you need a binomial (2 values) label.

Comment: But i used the Generate data operator and that does not have 3 values. Evan then i am having that problem. And how do i convert it to a binomial label. Thank you for your reply.